Compiling VHDL file with ```ghdl -a``` encountered error ```ghdl:error: installation problem: ghdl1-llvm not found```
I was recently trying to compile the .vhd file with ghdl  ghdl -a --ieee=synopsys --work=work Matrix_Data_Structure.vhd , the following error occurred :
ghdl:error: installation problem: ghdl1-llvm not found

I am running ghdl on the MacOS system, installed with brew
I tried to also install llvm and add path to zshrc :
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm@12/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm@12/lib"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm@12/include"' >> ~/.zshrc

as well as uninstall ghdl and reinstall ghdl, the same error message persisted
-------Edit: Extra Info---------------------------------------------
ghdl --version GHDL 4.1.0 (4.0.0.r39.g7188e92cf) [Dunoon edition]
OS version :macOS Sonoma version 14.6
GDHL path :/opt/homebrew/bin/ghdl 

Please provide locations and paths to the installed ghdl, URL for the formula/cask used to install ghdl (provides the URL fpr the downloaded ghdl install image), the host OS version and platform model, and the output of ghdl --version as well as locations and  file ghdl* and otool -L ghdl* A particular ghdl-llvm distributed build image can be particular of the location and version of libLLVM.so. The proper venue for installation problems would be https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/issues or communicating with the formula author (it may not be well maintained or accurate).

Did you verify whether ghdl1-llvm is in your PATH?

From the ghdl Issue we find this is a homebrew cask issue and from What topics can I ask about here? we find the question is off-topic here, see Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?.

The problem was solved by directly git clone from the ghdl repository then build and install it, then add path to zshrc:
# Clone the LLVM repository
git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
cd llvm-project

# Create a build directory
mkdir build
cd build

# Configure the build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/llvm ../llvm

# Build and install LLVM
make
sudo make install

# Add paths to .zshrc
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/llvm/lib"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/llvm/include"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/llvm/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

# Apply the changes
source ~/.zshrc

# Verify the installation
llvm-config --version

